# Calling theme_hook_suggestions inside template.php

Tags: 7, theming

I am using template_preprocess_block() to introduce a theme function like this:

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block_system_main_front';
```

but adding MY_THEME_block_system_main_front() to my template.php file does not change anything, MY_THEME_block_system_main_front() is not being called.

How can I introduce a custom theme function using theme_hook_suggestions and then use it like I use theme_image_formatter() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theme_hook_suggestions` is not for **function** suggestion, it is for [template suggestion](http://drupal.org/node/1089656).

In your case:

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block_system_main_front';
```

Drupal will try to load the file:

```
your_theme/templates/block-system-main-front.tpl.php
```